# Can I add a manager to a manytomany relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I have two models that has a manytomany relationship with a 'through' table in some way?

```
class Bike(models.Model):
   nickname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   users    = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='bike.BikeUser')
```

The BikeUser class

```
class BikeUser(models.Model):
   bike     = models.ForeignKey(Bike)
   user     = models.ForeignKey(User)
   comment  = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

I would like to add functionality to the Bike class for working with users, is there a best practice way of doing this. I would like to avoid adding too many methods to the Bike class and rather have some kind of manager to work through

Something like:

```
bike.bikeusers_set.commonMethod()
```

or

```
bike.bikeusers.commonMethod()
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have the BikeUser model, you can add a custom manager to the model.

Something like:

```
class BikeUserManager(models.Manager):
    def commonMethod():
        pass

class BikeUser(models.Model):
   bike     = models.ForeignKey(Bike)
   user     = models.ForeignKey(User)
   comment  = models.CharField(max_length=140)
   objects  = BikeUserManager()
```

But you can only use it from the BikeUser Model:

```
BikeUser.objects.commonMethod()
```

What you want is to use this manager as a related manager:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types

Add the `use_for_related_fields=True` to the manager class.

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm! Howerver, if I call the manager from an instanciated Bike
bike.bikeuser_set.commonMethod()
How do I access the "bike" from within the commonMethod?
(should this be a new question?)

Comment: I think you'll have to add it as a function parameter: def commonMethod(self,bike) and use it like this: bike.bikeuser_set.commonMethod(bike)

Comment: Thats what I'v been doing, I thought there was a better way, thank you very much anyways!

Answer (score 2):

**use_for_related_fields** is deprecated from django 2.0. Use for related fields is possible via [base manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access).

old:

```
class CustomManager(models.Model):
    use_for_related_fields = True

class Model(models.Model):
    custom_manager = CustomManager()
```

new:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    custom_manager = CustomManager()

    class Meta:
        base_manager_name = 'custom_manager'
```

[source of example](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/issues/290)

Remember about [restrictions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#don-t-filter-away-any-results-in-this-type-of-manager-subclass) for **get_queryset()** method.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def m2m_with_manager(related_manager, model_manager_name: str):
    """Replaces the default model manager tied to related manager with defined"""
    model_manager = getattr(related_manager.model, model_manager_name)
    return model_manager.filter(**related_manager.core_filters)
```

**Example**

for class `Author` and `Books`, where one `Author` can have multiple books

```
class Book:
   author = FK(Author, related_name='books')
   best = models.Manager(...)
```

**Usage**

```
wanted_qs = m2m_with_manager(author.books, model_manager_name='best')
```